# What is the namespace in routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I want priority a main Controller over a Area Controller (they names are equal).

The code in asp.net mvc is:

```
 name : "Default",
 pattern : "/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
 namespace:new []{"ProjectName.Controller"}
```

But it isn't in asp.net core mvc. how I add it?

The error is :

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
> ProjectName.Controllers.HomeController.Index (ProjectName)
> ProjectName.Areas.Admin.Controllers.HomeController.Index (ProjectName)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to use two controllers that have the same route, right?
Well the simplest solution would be to change the route of one of them. Right now both controllers can be accessed through `/Home/Index`.

You can add a `[Route]` attribute to one of the controllers or actions in order to change its route. Then the exception won't show up again.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core, you need to add **an area route**.

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "MyArea",
            pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

You can **[click this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-5.0#add-area-route)** to see a more detailed explanation.